# "drag control" for Android games

Tags: android

I am not very familiar with android development so maybe question will be not really about development process.

I noticed control in a bunch of different games where i can drag circle and in this way unit will move.

This is default control from some library or every developer just writes something similar?

Any examples or tutorials where i can get it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called an Analogue controller and most game development frameworks like [AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/) and [LibGDX](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/) offer it. Both such Engines are open source, and the code for this component in the AndEngine framework can be found [here](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/engine/camera/hud/controls/AnalogOnScreenControl.java).

However, you might want to consider using the game engine itself in your app, instead of picking up bits of it and writing your own.

Comment: I would strongly recommend LibGDX as you can use it as either a full engine or as parts of it.  In addition you can develop on the desktop and get HTML5 version automatically.  This project has a lot more momentum I think. Moreover there is very active community.  Be sure to sign up with forum, thats the best way to develop since both engines are not perfectly documented.

Comment: i've used both engines, and would also recommend LibGDX, though even AndEngine is really powerful.